# IIS Error: Cannot read configuration file because it exceeds the maximum file size

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis-7.5

I am trying to setup a webservice in my local IIS.
The webService was throwing 500.19 Error on browsing.
I found the size of web.config file for webservice is 1.17 Mb

Found solution like creating key as "MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB" in Registry at path HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB .

I referred:

[Setting MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB in IIS8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489866/setting-maxwebconfigfilesizeinkb-in-iis8-5)

[Can not read configuration file because it exceed the maximum file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169084/can-not-read-configuration-file-because-it-exceed-the-maximum-file-size)

But creating key didn't work for me.
Machine has Windows 7 installed with IIS 7.5. My machine is 32-bit.

[image]

I have also tried resetting IIS using CMD with command "iisreset". I do not want to split the web.config file as it is an already existing Web Service.

Comment: If your application runs in a 32-bit application pool then you'll also need to adjust the `SysWow64Node` version of the same registry value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208209/iis-8-0-asp-net-and-error-500-19

Comment: I can not see even Inetstp or Configuration etc at SysWow64Node folder. Do you think I should create everything there too?